# Indentify DSA/RSA keys in Perl

Tags: perl, rsa, gnupg, pgp, dsa

I am trying to find a Perl solution to identify the type of the keys.
I have a list of key files and I need to know which are DSA and which are RSA.

I know I can do it on Linux with the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -lf id_dsa.pub
```

I am trying to find a pure Perl solution that would work on both Windows and Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: There would be RFC or other specification documents out there that describe what these keys look like. Once you have them you should be able to implement parsers for them.

Comment: Have you ever looked at what is inside a public key file? because if you do, the answer to your question would be obvious!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File::LibMagic](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-LibMagic-1.15/lib/File/LibMagic.pm) which uses the same library as the unix `file` command.

On ubuntu, I installed it as:

```
apt-get install libmagic-dev

cpan File::LibMagic
```

For windows, it is known to work with Cygwin, and it should work with windows if you can install the libmagic libraries.  I haven't tried this, so YMMV.

**Example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::LibMagic;

my $magic = File::LibMagic->new();

my $key_dsa = '/home/felix/.ssh/id_dsa.pub';
my $info_dsa = $magic->info_from_filename( $key_dsa );
print "[ $key_dsa ] : " . $info_dsa->{description} . "\n";

my $key_rsa = '/home/felix/.ssh/id_rsa.pub';
my $info_rsa = $magic->info_from_filename( $key_rsa );
print "[ $key_rsa ] : " . $info_rsa->{description} . "\n";
```

**Output**

```
[ /home/felix/.ssh/id_dsa.pub ] : OpenSSH DSA public key
[ /home/felix/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ] : OpenSSH RSA public key
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Unfortunately, for Windows it requires Cygwin which I am trying to avoid using.

Comment: Yes I did. The installation failed on two different windows environment because of some dependencies.

Comment: You could just try reading the keys and seeing if it starts with `ssh-dss` for dsa or `ssh-rsa` for rsa.